# Azure Synapse: Performant way to promote data from staging schema to prod schema?

Tags: azure-synapse

I've used ADF/synapse pipeline to extract my fact data from source to staging schema table in dedicated sql pool.

My task now is to enrich the fact data with a surrogate key, which comes via lookup from a small dimension table already in prod schema.

I've been using ADF/synapse dataflow for this, but it seems inefficient because it's moving the data BACK into ADF. I could do this via spark notebook, but also seems like an unnecessary data movement.

So i *think* best approach is to make a stored procedure on the dedicated sql pool to perform this enrichment. My concern is to ensure this sql proc is coded in a performant way (not a row by row insert).

There are lots of proc examples that create a table from nothing (ctas), but I haven't found examples that do the enrich/append action in a scalable way. What are good sql code practices for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best practice for this would be to have your small dimension distributed as `REPLICATE` and use CTAS to create a `HASH` distributed table on a suitable column.  Consider partition switching in addition if you have enough volume.  A simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE fact.yourBigTable
WITH
(
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX,
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH( someColumn )
)
AS
SELECT ...
FROM staging. ...


CREATE TABLE dim.yourSmallTable (

    ...

)
WITH
(
    CLUSTERED INDEX ( someColumn ),
    DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE
);
```

CTAS is optimised to work well on the MPP infrastructure of dedicated SQL pools.  If you do not feel CTAS is appropriate look a straightforward `INSERT` instead.  Dedicated SQL pools now support `MERGE` (in preview) so that may also be worth a look.

I would agree with you not to use ADF or Dataflows for this as there's nothing faster than a bit of SQL running directly on the server and I reserve these things for things you can't do with SQL, eg orchestrations / running tasks in parallel, advanced transform (eg with notebooks) and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the dim is replicated across the shards, and yes the fact is hashed on a good column. The thing I don't think I got across well in my question is that this staging -> prod promotion/enrichment is an incremental load. Ie the fact table already exists in prod and is large. The new day's data (without surrogate key) is what's in staging and needs to have the surrogate key added before it can be moved to prod. That's why ctas didn't seem appropriate to me?

Comment: So as suggested, you can try `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` or `MERGE` if the volume for CTAS isn't appropriate.  Have you tried either of those?  You could also try chopping it into two stages, ie use CTAS to create a temp table with the surrogate key added, then upsert from there.  I'd try a couple of approaches, see what works best for your workload.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying - thanks. I had been shying away from the insert statement, because of bad performance experiences with it in ADF (bulk insert vs polybase/copy cmd). But possibly it's a different story with the data already in sql. I've give it a shot - thank you!